# Why does the wrappanel event fire before a child's event?

Tags: wpf, events, wrappanel

I have a WrapPanel that has a button as a child element.  Both the WrapPanel and the Button have the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event defined.

I have noticed that when I click the Button, the WrapPanel's event is fired before the Button's event.  Is there anyway to change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Preview*` events are [**tunneling**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies), they travel from the root to the source, so they are raised on the panel, which is closer to the root, first. Use the **bubbling** version (`MouseLeftButtonDown`) to have the event travel up the tree.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the property **IsHItTestVisible** to *false* then mouse triggered events like a clicks will be ignored.